# What's going on with package management after upgrading to 20.04LTS?

Tags: apt, upgrade, 20.04, xfce

I'm just tweaking my system after upgrading to 20.04LTS and I discovered that `apt`thinks I'm not using `clipman` when I absolutely am - I get this when running `apt`:

```
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  hddtemp libburn4 libglade2-0 libgtksourceview-3.0-1 libgtksourceview-3.0-common libisofs6 libjpeg-turbo-progs libjte2 libqrencode4 libxnvctrl0 mousepad ristretto xfburn
  xfce4-clipman xfce4-clipman-plugin xfce4-cpufreq-plugin xfce4-cpugraph-plugin xfce4-datetime-plugin xfce4-dict xfce4-diskperf-plugin xfce4-fsguard-plugin xfce4-genmon-plugin
  xfce4-mailwatch-plugin xfce4-netload-plugin xfce4-places-plugin xfce4-sensors-plugin xfce4-smartbookmark-plugin xfce4-systemload-plugin xfce4-taskmanager xfce4-timer-plugin
  xfce4-verve-plugin xfce4-wavelan-plugin xfce4-weather-plugin xfce4-xkb-plugin xscreensaver-data
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
```

Obviously I'm not keen on letting it autoremove that stuff since I'm fairly keen on my desktop. It's probably got something to do with `xfce` but that's just a wild guess. The system was originally installed with Ubuntu server 18.04 and then I installed `xfce` to add the gui. But that was over 18 months ago and this problem is new.

================

Debug info:

```
adam@gondolin:~$ sudo apt-mark showmanual | grep xfce4
[sudo] password for adam: 
libxfce4panel-2.0-4
libxfce4ui-1-0
libxfce4ui-2-0
libxfce4ui-common
libxfce4ui-utils
libxfce4util-bin
libxfce4util-common
libxfce4util7
xfce4
xfce4-appfinder
xfce4-appmenu-plugin
xfce4-indicator-plugin
xfce4-notifyd
xfce4-panel
xfce4-power-manager
xfce4-power-manager-data
xfce4-pulseaudio-plugin
xfce4-screenshooter
xfce4-session
xfce4-settings
xfce4-statusnotifier-plugin
xfce4-terminal
xfce4-whiskermenu-plugin
adam@gondolin:~$
```

and the second:

```
adam@gondolin:~$ sudo apt-mark showauto | grep xfce4
xfce4-clipman
xfce4-clipman-plugin
xfce4-cpufreq-plugin
xfce4-cpugraph-plugin
xfce4-datetime-plugin
xfce4-dict
xfce4-diskperf-plugin
xfce4-fsguard-plugin
xfce4-genmon-plugin
xfce4-mailwatch-plugin
xfce4-netload-plugin
xfce4-places-plugin
xfce4-power-manager-plugins
xfce4-screensaver
xfce4-sensors-plugin
xfce4-smartbookmark-plugin
xfce4-systemload-plugin
xfce4-taskmanager
xfce4-timer-plugin
xfce4-verve-plugin
xfce4-wavelan-plugin
xfce4-weather-plugin
xfce4-xkb-plugin
adam@gondolin:~$
```

Comment: `apt-mark showmanual | grep xfce4` and `apt-mark showauto | grep xfce4` please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good job checking your output! You just saved yourself some hassle.

First, let's check to see if the package is included in a desktop metapackage that was removed. The following tells us that the package `xfce4-clipman` is included with the base lxqt desktop, but not the base xfce desktop. For xfce users, it's optional.

```
$ apt rdepends xfce4-clipman
xfce4-clipman
Reverse Depends:
  Depends: lxqt
  Depends: xfce4-clipman-plugin
  Recommends: lxqt-core
```

There are two ways to tell the system that you really want a package after all (to make the package ineligible for autoremoval). Under the hood, these two methods do the same thing: They change the apt-marking from `auto` to `manual`:

```
$ sudo apt-mark manual <packagename>
$ sudo apt install <packagename>        // yes, even it it's already installed
```

If you later change your mind, and you don't want the package anymore:

```
$ sudo apt-mark auto <packagename>      // Do not remove now; just make eligible for autoremoval
$ sudo apt remove <packagename>         // Remove now; don't wait
```

Comment: OK, I see. Thanks. I was under the totally false impression that `apt` somehow just knew what packages I was using!